# Lining up text on display screen

Tags: c++, string, printing, spacing

I created a GPA Calculator that displays a transcript-like visual after all of the proper variables have been input. I'm having trouble lining everything up in an efficient way. I currently use long empty strings to separate the variables, but it's not extremely efficient. Is there a function that can properly line up all of my text in the way that I want?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u11Jr.png) is a sample of the display.

Below is the code for printing the display.

```
void print(vector<string> className, vector<double> creditHours, vector<string> letterGrade, vector<double> letterValue, int classCount) {
    double gpa = calculate(letterGrade, letterValue, creditHours, classCount);

    cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H"; // Flushes the screen

    cout << "************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Name          Weight          Grade" << endl << endl;

    //TODO Align all classes and numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < classCount; i++) {
            cout << className.at(i) << "            " << creditHours.at(i) << "               " << letterGrade.at(i) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "GPA: " << gpa << endl;
    cout << "************************************" << endl;
    cout << "(1) Rename Class  (2) Change Weight  (3) Change Grade   (4) Add Class  (5) Remove Class (6) Exit" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to do: ";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill). And copying a `std::vector` or a `std::string` (or even a `std::vector<std::string>` is not exactly a cheap operation so you should prefer passing a reference instead of a copy.